# Rescue Rack RangeError in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rack

I have a rails app with a GraphQL endpoint which accepts large amounts of data. A single post could easily be 500Kb. I have bumped the `key_space_limit`;

`Rack::Utils.key_space_limit = 8 * 65536`

but I would like to give API users a useful error if they exceed the 512kb limit. Currently it's a `500 Internal Server Error` which isn't ideal.

I have attempted rescue `RangeErrors` in the graphql controller

```
def execute
  ...
rescue RangeError => e
  render json: { error: { message: "message too large, please limit messages to 512Kb"}, data: {} }, status: 400
end
```

however I am still getting a `RangeError`;

```
2019-01-14 13:04:23 -0500: Rack app error handling request { POST /graphql }
#<RangeError: exceeded available parameter key space>
```

I'm also unable to replicate the issue in controller tests. This test does not fail as it would if run in development or production;

```
test "large posts should work" do
  request.headers['HTTP_ACCESS_TOKEN'] = @biometric_token.token
  lots_of_biometrics = ''

  10000.times do
    lots_of_biometrics += '''
      {
        value: 80
        type: weight
        source: "really long string that take up loads of space because"
        notes: "another really long string because we are testing large posts to the graphql endpoint"
      },
    '''
  end
  large_query = """
    mutation {
      BulkCreate(
        biometrics: [#{lots_of_biometrics}]
      ) {
        id
        records_total
      }
    }
  """

  Sidekiq::Testing.inline! do
    post :execute, format: :json, body: large_query
  end
  body = JSON.parse(response.body)
  assert_response :success
end
```

I assume the error is occurring at a higher level of abstraction than the controller. I'm aware of the DDoS risks in increasing `key_space_limit` so I assume this is by design. But does anyone have any suggestions on giving a useful response to API users when they exceed the limit?

Comment: You need to catch the error at the Rack level (not Rails), this article might help: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/catching-json-parse-errors-with-custom-middleware It will show you how you can write a custom middleware to catch JSON parsing error and return a nice 400 error to the end user. --- For the testing part, I suggest to wrap your tests with a block that redefines `Rack::Utils.key_space_limit` to something much smaller, run your test to ensure the "nice error" is returned properly, then re-set the `Rack::Utils.key_space_limit` to the previous value. It will save you perfs & exec time

Comment: Thank you @MrYoshiji! Do you know what middleware I should be inserting before?  `config.middleware.insert_before Rack::Utils, "CatchRangeErrors"` Or do you know how I could find that out? I'm not sure how to best trouble shoot this when I can't throw in a breakpoint and explore

Comment: I don't know where you should be inserting it, sadly. I suggest to list the current middlewares of your app (`YourApp::Application.config.middleware.middlewares`) and try inserting it as last middleware, if it does not work, try in the middle, if does not work, try 1st quarter, etc etc until you find the best spot. For the tests, you can simply set the `key_space_limit` to a ridiculous small number and `curl` your app with some data to trigger the Ranger Error. Sorry I cannot help you more than that :(